# How do I parse a text response to only bring back the token after "Access"

Tags: javascript, postman

I'm trying to do a pre-request script to retrieve a bearer auth token. I've gotten it to work but need to create a auth token constant from the response. The response comes back with two tokens, a refresh and access token. I would to retrieve the access token and assign it as a variable so that I can proceed to use it in my api calls.
[Postman Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLokj.png)

This is the response:
"refresh":"fjdasklfjsakldfjaslkfjlkasdf","access":"dsfjalskfjaslkdfjaklsdfjafdslfkja"

This is my first API project so any advice would be great! I've read about Access and Response tokens. Not sure how to incorporate both (or if I should). So far for testing i've been using the access token to try test API calls.

I've tried to parse the token by doing a startswith("access:").

Such as this:
`authHeader.startsWith("access")){ token = authHeader.substring(9, authHeader.length);

Comment: Are you sure the response doesn't have `{}` included? It looks like JSON except for that, and you would use `JSON.parse(response)`

Comment: also, please don't use screenshots. Insert your code in the question to better help others.  Glancing at it, it is trying to get `.access_token` but it looks like you just want `.access`

Comment: I think I understand. Looks like this is working

pm.sendRequest(getTokenRequest, (err, response) => {
  var responseJson = response.json();
    console.log(responseJson);
    pm.environment.set('ACCESS_TOKEN', responseJson['access_token']);

Answer (score 0):

In your pre-request script, retrieve the response body using pm.response.json():

1. const responseBody = pm.response.json();

Then, Access the access property of the response object:

2. const accessToken = responseBody.access;

Store the token in an environment variable for easier use in subsequent requests:

3. pm.environment.set("accessToken", accessToken);

pm.response.json() parses the response body as JSON, allowing you to access its properties.and responseBody.access directly extracts the access token from the JSON object. lastly Setting an environment variable with pm.environment.set() makes it accessible across requests.

I hope it will help you!